# Intellij - Private final string somehow null

Tags: variables, intellij-idea, final

I have the following line in my class:

```
public class myClass {
   private final String MY_VAR = "PY-PP";

...
}
```

But somehow whenever I inspect my code in debug, that variable is null, it is not being used anywhere except in 1 place to read, any ideas?

I have tried invalidating caches, rebuilding whole project and redeploying the server with no luck, this is a brand new intellij install as well.

Comment: Could you give an example of creating an instance of this class and calling this variable?

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).